# The grammar of ‘things I hoped wouldn’t happen’

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I’m looking for the name of the grammar used in the phrase and what type of verbs can be used i. this way and some explanation as to the rule for using it:

> Some things I hoped wouldn’t happen in my life.

I understand the meaning so I’m mainly looking for a name/rule for the grammar that is verb + will/would + verb and what verbs can do this.

Thank-you in advance!

Comment: Not really sure what exactly you are after. It's just a regular sentence. *Will* is a helper verb. Any other word in it you can replace with a different word no problem. I hoped that some things wouldn't happen. She thought that Elvis would propose to her. The boys expected that their father would buy them a Playstation. Not sure what you mean by "what verbs can do this". Do what exactly. And what do you mean "the name of the grammar". English has exactly one grammar, it's called "the English grammar".

Comment: [Relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause)?

Comment: I mean that you can’t say ‘I eat some things will~~’ so what verbs can you use in sentences with ‘I verb object will/would’ (and not I verb object that will/would)